# Grunt include-replace string unexpexted token error / special characters in string

Tags: html, gruntjs, gruntfile, grunt-includes

When I'm adding a string to the [grunt-include-replace](https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace) includes like shown below, I get an 'unexpected token error' in the console and the html file doesn't compile.

```
@@include('components/navigation.html', {
  "list-elements": "<li><a href="#">home</a></li>"
})
```

I think there are problems with the special characters <>/#".

How can I make those characters work in the string?

Comment: Try with this: `'<li><a href="#">home</a></li>'` Btw, usually the unexpected token error in Chrome says afterwards the character that breaks the thread. Something like this: `Unexpected token .` If you get that, please post it.

Comment: The terminal console gives the following output:
`running "includereplace:all" (includereplace) task
>> Processing app/src/index.html
Warning: Unexpected token ' Use --force to continue.`

Comment: This is a JSON error. I solved the problem with escaping the quotes by adding backslashes.

    @@include('components/navigation.html', {
      "list-elements": "<li><a href=\"#\">home</a></li>"
    })

Comment: Please, post that as an answer and mark it accepted.